# Identify spectral bands in a multispectral raster dataset

Tags: gdal, c++, multi-band

I'm trying to make an application to use on precision agriculture using gdal, and want to give it some flexibility to support imagery from different providers.

I've been looking around if there's a way to identify the bands in a multispectral image despite the provider.
I used gdalinfo with some raster datasets from Landsat, Spot6 and Sentinel-2, but the only hint it gives I could use is Color interpretation, which is not very useful.

I get gray for the individual bands of the Sentinel-2 image, and Red, Green, Blue, and Unidentified for landsat and spot6 stacked datasets I prepared on ArcGIS.

Is there a way to identify each band from the metadata, the header of the tiff image or something, so my program can identify each band without me telling it each time I use a dataset from a different provider?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no real system behind what kind of additional information is provided in the metadata elements of the given raster.

As such, you should probably just create a 'preprocessing' chain, which determines which satellite the data is from, based on the associated metadata, and then deals with each of them separately. This will likely be a toolbox that you can reuse again and again across multiple projects, as such basic datahandling elements will occur in most applications relying on satellite imagery from multiple data providers.